# JavaScript Swiper Pagination background transition delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, swiper.js

I am creating a Slider using HTML. Each slide contains an image and text.

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide slide1"><img src="background-images/slide1.png"><h1>Slide 1</h1></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide2"><img src="background-images/slide2.png"><h1>Slide 2</h1></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide3"><img src="background-images/slide3.png"><h1>Slide 3</h1></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide4"><img src="background-images/slide4.png"><h1>Slide 4</h1></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide5"><img src="background-images/slide5.png"><h1>Slide 5</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

When the slide changes, the background color of the slide should change. I have done this using the following CSS code:

```
.slide1 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.slide2 {
    background-color: #008000;
}
.slide3 {
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

This works as expected.

The background color of the swiper-pagination div should also change.
However, this does not work as expected. I have tried writing multiple different lines of code to do this including:

```
swiper.on('slideChangeTransitionEnd', () => {
    const currentSlide = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active');
    const slideNumber = currentSlide.classList[1];
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        pagination.style.backgroundColor = 
        getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(`.${slideNumber}`)).backgroundColor;
    }, 50);
});
```

This code does affect the amount of time taken to change the color of the swiper-pagination div as if I increase the value which is currently 50, the swiper-pagination div will take more time to change color.

I want to remove the time delay between when the background color of the slide and the background color of the swiper-pagination div change. I have tried changing the value which is 50 to lower values, such as 0 and negative values such as -50. However, this does not completely remove the amount of time between when the background color of the slide and the swiper-pagination divs change.

This time delay only occurs when swiping through the slider or when the swiper changes slides automatically. The code I have written for the next and previous buttons is below:

```
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const currentSlide = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active');
    const slideNumber = currentSlide.classList[1];
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        pagination.style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(`.${slideNumber}`)).backgroundColor;
                }, 50);
});
        
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const currentSlide = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active');
    const slideNumber = currentSlide.classList[1];
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    pagination.style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(`.${slideNumber}`)).backgroundColor;
            }, 50);
        });
```

This code correctly changes the background color of the slide and the swiper pagination divs at the same time without any delay.

I have created a Code Pen containing the code I have written. The images may not look correct on this Pen due to the dimensions.
https://codepen.io/programmer90000/pen/ZEmMoaq

Comment: I wasn't capable of running your program and I don't know why; but I know something, that 50 means 50miliseconds and that's not so much, the question is the delay you're facing is 50miliseconds or more, as if it's more it means that there might be another `setTimeout` in the library or perhaps the minimum time that your code could be run is that long

Comment: When I click on the previous or next buttons, both divs change color at the same time. The issue is when I try to swipe trough the slides, the divs change color at different times.

Comment: _"When the slide changes, the background color of the slide should change. I have done this using the following CSS code:"_ - okay, so you have not actually done anything to _dynamically_ change the slide background colors, you have just given each of them a _fixed_ background color. So the background color will "move with" the slides. Maybe that is somehow the root of your issue already ...? It's hard to tell, by just seeing these snippets. Could you please try and assemble all of this into a proper [mre], so that we can check for ourselves?

Comment: Yes, looks like that is actually your issue. When clicking the buttons, you change the pagination background immediately, before the slides even start to move. But with `slideChangeTransitionEnd`, you are triggering the change only when the slides have _finished_ moving. Maybe you should bind this to `slideChangeTransitionStart` instead ...? (And then you probably won't even need the click handlers for the prev/next buttons any more.)

Comment: I have added a link to Code Pen containing the code I have written. The images may not look correct due to the dimensions. However, the JavaScript is working the same.

Comment: Not having much luck with any of the events - like I said, likely due to the fact, that the background color is moving _with_ the slides, so I suppose you would have to switch the pagination background color in the _middle_ of the transition, to at least get a halfway consistent look. It might be better, if you just left the pagination background transparent - and positioned it absolute, so that the background of the slides can shine through. (Maybe a bit of padding-bottom on either the slides or the container, to make room.)

Comment: slideChangeTransitionStart has worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ```slideChangeTransitionEnd' to 'slideChangeTransitionStart'.

For example:

```
swiper.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', () => {
    const currentSlide = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active');
    const slideNumber = currentSlide.classList[1];
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        pagination.style.backgroundColor = 
        getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(`.${slideNumber}`)).backgroundColor;
    }, 50);
});
```